# calculation of bits needed

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

I need help with this

I was asked that for an unsigned integer range 1 to 1 billion, ,how many bits are needed!

How do we calculate this?

Thank you

UPDATE!!!!

This what I wanted to know because the interviwer said **17**

Comment: use your calculator for log2(10^9)

Comment: What part of base 2 confuses you?  Could you be more specific on what you can't figure out?

Comment: And if your calculator doesn't have log_2 built in, you can exploit that log_b(x) = log_k(x)/log_k(b) (i.e. log_2(1e9) = log(1e9)/log(2)).

Comment: If your interviewer said 17 then he's either just plain wrong, or you aren't giving us the whole question.

Comment: Either your interviewer is an idiot, or you've mis-stated the question. 17 bits will get you any number from 0 to 131071. If you start at 1, you can represent numbers up to 131072.

Comment: len("an unsigned integer range 1 to 1 billion")*8 = 320.

Comment: I am very sure, this is the exact question he phrased

Comment: The interviewer must have confused between 1 lakh and 1 billion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate `log2(1000000000)` and round it up. It works out to 30 bits.

For example in Python you can calculate it like this:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(math.log(1000000000, 2))
30.0
```

Answer (score 7):

Take the log base 2 of 1 billion and round up.

Alternatively, you should know that integers (with over 4 billion values) require 32-bits, therefore for 2 billion you'd need 31-bits and for 1 billion, 30-bits.

Another handy thing to know is that every 10 bits increase the number of values you can represent by a factor just over 1000 (1024), so for 1000, you need 10 bits, 1 million needs 20 bits, and 1 billion needs 30 bits.

Answer (score 2):

```
2^10 = 1024
2^10 * 2^10 = 2^20 = 1024*1024 = 1048576
2^10 * 2^10 * 2^10 = 2^30 = 3 * 1024 ~= 1,000,000
```

=> 30 Bits